# Is there a difference between generating and loading data?

Tags: import, random, distributions, sampling

**EDIT-1**

This is a minimal example where an error occurs after 44538 samples generated in `d1` upon importing as `d2`. Note that if `d1` is used as parameter for `SmoothKernelDistribution` it is still okay, so there seems to be a problem with the import.

```
d1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100000];

Export["d1TEST.txt", d1];

d2 = Flatten[Import["d1TEST.txt", "Table"]];

\[ScriptCapitalD]1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[d2];
```

> SmoothKernelDistribution::invldd: The input data
> SmoothKernelDistribution[{6617.53,7952.92,<<47>>,7810.37,<<99950>>}]
> should be a vector or a matrix of real numbers or a valid TemporalData
> object.

---

**Original post**

I have a code in which I write

```
empiricPDF1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[RandomVariable1Histogram];
d1 = RandomVariate[empiricPDF1, 100000];
isexpan = Transpose[ALPHAHATis].Simplify[PHI]; 
simis = Table[
   isexpan /. {z1 -> d1[[k]], z2 -> d2[[k]]}, {k, 1, nsim}];
timesample1 = simis[[1 ;; All, 688]]
\[ScriptCapitalD]1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[timesample1];
```

This takes a long time to run since it has to generate a random sample of a big size. I want to save the vector d1 so that I don't have to generate it time and again and also have a constant sample to study. I save the data as

```
Export["d1_2RVConflictBC.txt", d1];
```

And then, instead of generating d1, I load it as

```
d1 = Flatten[Import["d1_2RVConflictBC.txt", "Table"]];
```

Unfortunately, when I arrive to

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[timesample1];
```

I get an error

```
SmoothKernelDistribution::invldd: The input data SmoothKernelDistribution[{6617.53,7952.92,<<47>>,7810.37,<<99950>>}] should be a vector or a matrix of real numbers or a valid TemporalData object.
```

which I don't understand. I don't get why it happens. As can be seen in the first attached figure, `d1` is the same in both versions of the code and so is the value of time sample. So, I don't understand why the error mentioned above (and in the second attached figure) appears.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `empiricPDF1 ` is not computing. Please add the definition of  `RandomVariable1Histogram`?

Comment: @Syed I am afraid that I load it from a file as `RandomVariable1Histogram = Flatten[Import["RV1txt.txt", "Table"]];`, it is a 50*1 vector

Comment: `isexpan = Transpose[ALPHAHATis].Simplify[PHI]; ` is not evaluating either. Please add enough data to your post to create a **minimal working example** that is copy-paste-able. Also the data you have posted as a comment can be deleted after you have added it to your post. A presumptive answer to your question is that there is no difference in loading and generating data, if executing `listA==listB` returns True where `listA` is the generated data and the `listB` is the loaded data.

Comment: @Syed Very well, I have added the example to the question. The most annoying thing is that it works if I write `d1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000];`

Comment: Up to `44538` samples, the output D2 is okay and then it throws an error and I certainly don't know why. I am on v12.2.0 and this could also be version dependent.

Comment: @Syed I see. Thanks for your answers anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always prudent to use the same format in Export and Import. Consider:

```
Export["d1TEST.txt", d1]
```

and

```
Export["d1TEST.txt", d1,"Table"]
```

do not export the same format.

For example:

```
d1={6.064691740996638*^-6, 1.}
Export["test1.txt",d1]
```

writes a file with:

```
6.064691740996638*^-6
1.
```

On the other hand:

```
Export["test2.txt",d1,"Table"]
```

writes:

```
6.064691740996638e-6
1.
```

Note the difference in the exponent. On import with the command:

```
Import["d1TEST.txt", "Table"]
```

6.064691740996638*^-6 is imported as a string, what creates the error.

Comment: Can you tell if OP’s fix is to merely just remove the `“Table”` part of their call to `Import`?

Comment: No, I would use "Table" both on Export and Import.

Comment: Actually, I most probably wouldn't use a text format for that purpose at all :-) But whatever format is used, it certainly is a good idea to read the same format that has been written...